automatically fetch the router address and the corresponding ABI
So, here's the situation: for the bot I'm creating, there is a swap function, and I want it to work across various DEXs. As far as I understand, I need the router address and ABI for each DEX to perform this.
Currently, I manually store the router addresses of different DEXs in a config file, and for each DEX, I have a separate JSON file containing its ABI that the code references.
Obviously, this is a cumbersome process, and I would like the code to automatically fetch the router address and the corresponding ABI.
From what I understand, it's common to use APIs connected to platforms like Etherscan and similar, or use tools like Brownie to find this information automatically. However, I’d like to avoid Brownie for now as I find it a bit complicated at this stage and using API with scannes.
That’s about it. Thanks a lot for the help!
